# select statement inside select extract

Tags: sql, postgresql, vertica

I have the following sql statement

```
SELECT
(EXTRACT (SECOND FROM TIME '00:34:01.024416') * 1000) :: int AS "second-millisecond"
```

The problem is that the interval is a String and it is static, is it possible to replace '00:34:01.024416' with a SQL statement that returns a interval? if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you need to put the `TIME` with the select though. It isn't the `EXTRACT` that is the problem.

```
SELECT (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM ( SELECT TIME '00:34:01.024416' ) ) * 1000) :: int AS "second-millisecond";
```

As long as the subselect itself returns an interval, you should be fine.

Comment: Excellent answer. However, I almost downvoted due to spaces between casting `int`

Comment: @Up_One I might also know who `woot` is and this might be an inside joke

Comment: @Kermit, just joking - we all know who you are :), just respect for you.